Creating higher voltage from DC motor
I have a DC motor (5 V, 600 rpm). I use it as a generator. It produces near 1.5 V max.
This voltage may differ while using it in the application and I can't control it. I want to raise this voltage to 5 V.
Can I use a DC-DC step-up converters, or do these converters only work with a stable inputneed like a battery?

You can and should, but it might not be straight forward. You will need to store 5V in a capacitor or battery rather than powering the pwm controller straight from the generator. And perhaps it should be a microcontroller and some external parts rather than just a normal boost dc/dc, so you could tweak control parameters.
